# Android: Creating custom view

Tags: android, view

In my app I'm trying to create my own HorizontalScrollView that "snaps" when you swipe through the views inside of it. Everytime it tries to load the layout, it crashes. So, I'm taking baby steps. I'm new to creating custom views programmatically, so if there may be some "common sense" mistakes.

Here is my `CustomView.java` file:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity.java` file:

```
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }
}
```

Here is my `main_layout.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lchoose_weapon"
    tools:context=".ChooseWeaponActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Title"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<com.javaknight.ultimaterps.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/CustomVw"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CustomVm"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Another TextView Below" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bOK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="ok" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using the following code fails to display the layout. As soon as I remove the CustomView from the xml file, it works fine. I want the xml layout file to have the Custom View inside of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should create all the constructors in your custom View:

```
public CusatomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

If you do it, I guess your layout will work.